# Maui Map Control, Display Business Name without clicking pin

Tags: dictionary, controls, maui

I want to display the Google Map API business name by the pin like the Google Maps app by default without clicking anything. I currently can load several pins dynamically, but I must click each pin using the Android emulator to see any information, such as name.

I have researched and found nothing for .Net 6 or .Net 7. I found some similar sample code, but it uses .Net 8 Preview which I ended up removing.

Comment: .NET 8 will be released in a few weeks

Comment: You can create the map by using the [Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps/)